# Find a word(noun) whose initial is "R" and whose thesaurus is "question"

Tags: single-word-requests

There are many words that express **confusion and uncertainty** about something,
for example: **question/doubt/haze** ...

But I can't find a similar word starting with the letter "**R**". I have been looking for it a whole day, however, the result is disappointing.

Comment: Recondite, perhaps.

Comment: Recherche is also possible although, like @V.V.'s suggestion, it refers to the subject and not the person

Comment: Reconsider, perhaps?

Comment: The only words I've been able to find that have somewhat the right flavor are reluctance, reservation, reserve, and reticence. Others have already mentioned the first two (and reservation and reserve are related).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because asking for a word which may or may not exist but must begin with _r_ is too narrowly scoped. There is also the problem that there is no mention of which thesauri have already been checked.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I agree to close this question as the reasonable explanations you have given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about, "I have my **reservations** about the accuracy of his theory."

To have **reservations**: Noun. *A doubt or feeling of not being able to agree with or accept something completely* (Cambridge Dictionary online)

Comment: So far, 'reservation' is the best answers. Thank you!

Comment: @HUANGTaizi In Peter Point's suggestion, the noun _must_ be in the plural: _reservations_ is correct, but _reservation_ is not. It's just how the idiom works.

Answer (score -1):

The only word I can think of that isn't blatantly obvious or easily checked is "reluctance/reluctant" (in this context, questionable); e.g., "he showed great reluctance when offered a drink"; or "he was reluctant to accept the drink."

Comment: How does _"reluctance"_ address either _"confused"_ or _"uncertain"_? Reluctance implies that the person would _rather not_ do something (unwillingness or disinclination - http://www.dictionary.com/browse/reluctance?s=ts). Therefore, they do _have a definite opinion_, so they are not uncertain (which implies no definite opinion), and they are not confused (which implies being unable to form an opinion).